# Change default domain of an PLESK Abonnement

Tags: parallel-processing, plesk

for the administration of multiple domains I use PLESK 12 on Ubuntu 10.04. 
An abonnement in my Plesk installation has a default domain and also a second domain.

As the second domain has to become the new default domain I want to change these two. I'm not able just to delete the abonnement and recreate it because there are services (email, hosting, etc.) running on both domains.

As plesk doesn't support an "option field" for setting the default domain I tried to rename the current default domain with the name of the second domain which didn't work for me.

Can anybody tell me the best way for getting this done?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the goal to make second domain as "default domain"?

Comment: The current default domain is the old one and has to be deactivated. All services should run under the new one.

Answer (score 0):

In pure case, if we are talking only about "name" to solve this you can rename in two steps:

1. second domain -> some-temporary-name,
2. default domain -> second domain

Unfortunately, as you want to keep access to mail of second domain you can't just rename it this way, because mail files are physically stored on file system in `/var/qmail/mailname/<second domain name(some-temporary-name)>/`

For web files you can just copy everything(in Plesk UI or FTP or shell) from `/second-domain-subfolder/` to `/httpdocs/`, but for mail files you should have root access to server and preserver files permissions in `/var/qmail/mailname/`

For only deactivating, you can disable primary domain only in "hosting settings" of this domain:
[image: plesk domain management]